# Other Users cannot login because of Excel File Import

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, epplus, database-administration, server-administration

I am importing List through Ep-Plus library( excel file) into db table. I run all queries together than perform commit. I cannot use bulk insert in this scenario for better performance because before inserting I check whether there is any duplicate records based on From Date and To Date.

The code does the job.

The problem is that while the activity is performed, the login does not open for any other user.

Can anyone tell me what is the reason for this issue? Is the issue with the db server or application server?

Comment: What does "the login doesn't open" mean?

Comment: It means the spinner to the top left of the browser keeps on moving and login page is not rendered as if connection timed out will appear.

Comment: Sounds like you are locking the main thread in the web app.  Have you tried putting the epplus loading logic on a background thread?